# Encoding problem when accessing to Windows via SSH

Tags: ssh

When trying to connect to my Windows 7 with Ubuntu 17.10 via SSH, I get some encoding and formatting problems, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: I think this is a Windows question, since this is SSH being served from a Windows system.  Use PuTTY on another Windows system, and see if you get the same issue when SSH'd into your Windows 7 system.  If the issue persists there, then this question is only tangentially Ubuntu related, and you should start debugging SSH on Windows as the core problem.

Comment: PuTTY is also available for Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows to Windows works fine, the same for Ubuntu to Ubuntu. I don't think much can be done in the server side (Windows 7).
It seems that PuTTY don't work in Ubuntu 17.10